# ¿Qué debo añadir a un archivo JavaScript para crear un ejecutable en Node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ubuntu, unix

Estoy tratando de crear un ejecutable en la consola de Ubuntu, pero no lo consigo.
La verdad es que solo he probado con el siguiente comando, puesto por más que busco en Google, no encuentro nada.
Busque las posibles preguntas en Stack, pero ninguna me convencio.

Esto es lo que añado al principio de mi archivo, sin éxito:

```
#!/bin/node
```

¿Qué debo añadir a un archivo JavaScript para crear un ejecutable en Node.js?

Comment: Hola Mari Cruz, ¿cómo tratas de ejecutar el fichero y qué errores recibes al hacerlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sustituye la línea que has puesto por esta otra ([fuente](http://robdodson.me/how-to-run-a-node-script-from-the-command-line/)):

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
```

Esa línea de código (que debe ir al principio del fichero) le indica al sistema que debe usar Node para ejecutar el script.

Así por ejemplo, si tienes guardas lo siguiente en un fichero llamado holamundo.js:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

console.log("Hola Mundo!");
```

y lo ejecutas desde la línea de comandos haciendo `./holamundo.js` (importante: el fichero debe tener permisos de ejecución que puedes añadir con `chmod`, de lo contrario recibirás un error), entonces el resultado será:

> Hola Mundo!

Comment: `env` viene a ser un "busca dónde está node" y la mayoría de gente lo recomienda. Yo habría indicado que uno lo busque con `which node` y aplique en el fichero el resultado de ese comando. [En Unix & Linux hablan de algo más complejo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65295/40596).